# Grothendieck and Segre's proof of the Hodge Index theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

On a field of positive characteristic we have the following well-known and important result:

> (**Hodge Index theorem**) Let $H$ be an ample divisor on a surface
>   $X$, and suppose that $D$ is a divisor, $D \not \equiv 0$, with
>   $D.H=0$. Then $D^2<0$.

It was independently proven in:

- Beniamino Segre, *Intorno ad un teorema di Hodge sulla teoria della base per la curve di una superficie algebraic* (1937)
- Alexander Grothendieck, [*Sur une note de Mattuck-Tate*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002178125&IDDOC=251958) (1958)

My question is:

> **Are those proofs essentially the same as the one on Hartshorne's**
>   **Algebraic Geomtry book?** (chapter V, section 1)

Comment: Grothendieck's is available online http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002178125&IDDOC=251958